# Как в Django-приложении обновлять title другой (не текущей) страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Изначально в браузере открыто 2 страницы: домашняя `home.html` и страница запросов `requests.html`. Стоит задача, чтобы при серфинге по различным страницам автоматически обновлялся `title` страницы `requests.html`. Title должен показывать количество посещённых во время серфинга страниц. Это похоже на то, как на сайте **Вконтакте** обновляется title с количеством новых сообщений.
Подскажите как это реализовать с помощью связки **Django+AJAX+jQuery**.

Answer (score 1):

У вас несколько вариантов

1. Реализовать это на фронтенде, используя localstorage. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/31514/) ну и поискать по ключевым словам "взаимодействие между страницами javascript localstorage". Из плюсов - никаких дополнительных запросов на сервер
2. Реализовать через какое-нибудь api и long pooling, например (можно веб-сокеты, но они с джангой не очень дружат) и обновлять title страницы. Из минусов - много лишних запросов на каждой открытой вкладке

Comment: Спасибо! Своим умом уже дошёл до применения localstorage. Но за ссылку на пример всё равно благодарю!